# jvectormap not displaying map on internet explore compatibility mode or < IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, jvectormap

I'm having a heck of a time getting a map to render properly in IE8 or IE compatibility mode.  I've tried examples and demos, I've changed maps multiple times... All features seem to work and look great except IE compatibility mode or antiquated versions of IE. Maps ARE rendering on IE8 or below on the jvectormap website just not for the examples offered.

I've even gone as far as trying to replicate the maps on http://jvectormap.com, linking right to it's JS files.  Still nothing.

Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the link you gave. The only issue I see is an absence of region border in IE8 or compatibility mode. The problem behind this is inability of VML engine to render borders with fractional width. Setting border as 1 makes the example work as expected.